# How to export entire command output to be used in another script

Tags: bash, variables, command, export

This question may sound silly but I haven't been able to solve perhaps someone could help me.

I have a script called `a.sh`

```
# a.sh
source b.sh [ARGUMENT1] [ARGUMENT2]

echo "Running binding script"
echo $b_output
```

And here is what is on the `b.sh` script

```
# b.sh
b_output=$(virsh update-device "$1" "$2" --live --persistent)
export b_output
```

When you run `virsh update-device...` command in the terminal, the output of the command if succeded is the following:

```
>virsh update-device [ARGUMENT1] [ARGUMENT2] --live --persistent
Device updated successfully
```

However, When I run `a.sh` this is what I get:

```
Running binding script
Device
```

Is there a way I can export the entire output of the command run in the `b.sh` script, instead of only displaying the first word?

Comment: what's the output of `echo "$(virsh update-device [ARGUMENT1] [ARGUMENT2] --live --persistent)"`?

Comment: Let me try to see what is the output

Comment: Output: Device updated successfully

Comment: OK, I don't see any trivial error in your scripts, they should work as expected; replacing `echo $b_output` with `echo "$b_output"` would be better but that won't fix the problem, which is probably related to the content of `[ARGUMENT1]` `[ARGUMENT2]`.

Comment: change `echo $b_output` to `echo "$b_output" | hexdump -C` to see if there are any special chars.